# error: no such device grub rescue Windows 7

Tags: boot, 14.04, windows-7, grubrescue

I have a hard drive with Windows 7 installed on and I wanted to install Ubuntu 12.04 onto an external hard drive. So I made a LiveUSB with Ubuntu 12.04 on and installed it to the external hard drive. I then deleted the partition and re-formatted the external hard drive that had Ubuntu on.

When I go to turn on my laptop now (with the Windows 7 hard drive) I get this.

```
error: no such device: c74908d5-9525-4fdc-a89a-cfa380052200.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue> ls
(hd0) (hd0,msdos3) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)
grub rescue>
```

I do not have the original disk that contained the Windows 7 OS on, I have seen from other forums that this can be used to repair the boot loader for windows. So obviously I am in a sticky situation.

I have another external hard drive with Ubuntu 14.04 on and when I connect an external hard drive case with the Windows 7 hard drive on. I can access these folders from Ubuntu 14.04.

[System](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kBMN.png):
[image]

[Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1llIT.png):
[image]

If anyone has any help as to how I can fix this problem, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Hope it helps! http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/776643-how-to-rescue-a-non-booting-grub-2-on-linux

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a Windows repair/recovery disc (which can be used to fix the bootloader), and don't have a copy of Ubuntu or some other Linux installed elsewhere (which can also be used to fix the bootloader), you may boot from a LiveCD of Ubuntu and [then move the bootloader to Windows](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1359802&p=10022261#post10022261):

```
sudo apt-get install lilo
sudo lilo -M /dev/sda mbr
```

To check which disk (e.g. `/dev/sda`) contains your Windows partition, use the *Disks* application available on the LiveCD.